# how to json_encode 'php array'

Tags: php, json

i have the following array like this :

```
{"label":"label1","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]}
{"label":"label","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]}
```

how to get string character (,) beetween {"label":"label1","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]} and {"label":"label2","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]}
result like this..

```
{"label":"label1","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]},
{"label":"label","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]}
```

**Code**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    $int = $row['SC'];
    $join = intval($int);
    $int2 = $row['jam'];
    $join2 = intval($int2);
    $dataset1[] = array($join2,$join);

}
for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { 
$dataset = array(label => label1, data => $dataset1);
$final = json_encode($dataset);

echo $final;
```

Comment: Using mysql_fetch_assoc! Then read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: but really, using `mysqli_...`, because `msql_...` has been removed from PHP.

Comment: Sure you don't mean `$dataset1[$i]` in that for loop? Or are you seriously dumping the same thing over and over?

Comment: This code only produces one {label....} object.  How you would join two or more of them depends on how you generate the others.

Comment: What is `$label = label` doing? Should that be `$label[] = $row['label']`?

Comment: @BradChristie yes i'm seriously dumping the same thing over and over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put everything into another array:

```
$dataset = array();
foreach ($dataset1 as $d) {
    $dataset[] = array('label' => $label, 'data' => $d);
}
$final = json_encode($dataset);
echo $final;
```

This should output:

```
[{"label":"label1","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]},
 {"label":"label","data":[[10,55],[15,32],[16,49]]}]
```